# kotlin reflection java long[] field err:java.lang.ClassCastException: long[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: kotlin

Error:

> kotlin reflection java long[] field err:java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   long[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

```
public class LongArrayDemo {

private long[] array = new long[2];

public static void main(String[] arg){
    LongArrayReflection.Companion.test();
}
}
```

```
class LongArrayReflection {

companion object {

   public fun test() {
       val demo = LongArrayDemo()
       val field = LongArrayDemo::class.java.getDeclaredField("array")
       field.isAccessible = true
        //I want get array(long[]) value
        val array = field.get(demo) as LongArray

   }
} }
```

Comment: hey, which versions of Java and Kotlin you are using? I'm just checked your example and it works fine

Comment: I use it in android project。 `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50` `compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }`